# Export in a Root Angular Module

Tags: angular

Why in an angular application the root module needs to be exported when no other module imports it?

Here is my snippet

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HerosComponent } from './heros/heros.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail/hero-detail.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HerosComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, HerosComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: what do you mean by root module?

Answer (score 3):

The `AppModule` class has a typescript `export` keyword, because it is imported by `main.ts` to startup the Angular application:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule( AppModule );
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a **Bootstrap process** inside the **main.ts**. There are many ways to bootstrap an application. The variations depend upon how you want to compile the application and where you want to run it. In the beginning, you will compile the application dynamically with the `Just-in-Time (JIT)` compiler and you'll run it in a browser. ([More about Just-in-time and Ahead-of-time compilation in angular here.](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler))

The recommended place by angular team to bootstrap a JIT-compiled browser application is in a separate file in the `src` folder named `src/main.ts`. So the `AppModule` should be exported in order to use it inside the `main.ts`.

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule }              from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

This code creates a browser platform for dynamic (JIT) compilation and bootstraps the AppModule described above.

The bootstrapping process sets up the execution environment, digs the root `AppComponent` out of the module's bootstrap array, creates an instance of the component and inserts it within the element tag identified by the component's selector.

source: 
[Angular docs archives](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/appmodule.html)